# Getting sslhandshake issue when calling httpclient.execute(httpPost)

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

```java
     try {
          sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(getWindowsKeyStore(), getSSLKeyPassword().toCharArray()).build();
          sslcontext.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
          SSLContext.setDefault(sslcontext);
     } catch (Exception e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }
     
     SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
               sslcontext,
               new String[] {"SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1","TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" },  // important
               null,
               SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
     
     RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000)
             .setConnectTimeout(10000).setSocketTimeout(60000).build();
     
     PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager = getHttpCLientConnManager(
             RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                     .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).register("https", sslsf)
                     .build());
     
     DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrat = new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {

         @Override
         public long getKeepAliveDuration(
                 HttpResponse response,
                 HttpContext context) {
             long keepAlive = super.getKeepAliveDuration(response, context);
             if (keepAlive == -1) {
                 keepAlive = 5000;
             }
             return keepAlive;
         }

     };
     
     httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
             .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
             .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
             .setConnectionTimeToLive(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
             .setConnectionManager(httpClientConnectionManager)
             .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrat)
             .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(10, true))
             .setMaxConnPerRoute(20).setMaxConnTotal(100)
             .build();
 
     return httpclient;
 }

private static KeyStore getWindowsKeyStore() {
     KeyStore keyStore = null;
     try {
          keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
          String sslPassword = getSSLKeyPassword();
          keyStore.load(null, sslPassword.toCharArray());
          
          List<String> alias = Collections.list(keyStore.aliases()).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
          System.out.println("alias name: " + alias.get(1)); 
          
         Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias.get(1));
         keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert", certificate);
     } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return keyStore;
 }
```

I've tried several options like:

- Incompatible versions of SSL in use Server: TLS v1, while the client SSL v3
- Incompatible cipher suites in use by the client and the server.
- Incomplete trust path for the server certificate;
- Upgrade httpclient to 4.5.6

  Stacktrace:

  pool-48-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
  pool-48-thread-1, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
  pool-48-thread-1, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
  pool-48-thread-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
  %% Invalidated:  [Session-79, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
  %% Invalidated:  [Session-178, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
  pool-48-thread-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
  pool-48-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
  pool-48-thread-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
  pool-48-thread-1, called closeSocket()
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java381) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
  [pool-20-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.Poolinjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
  at java.net.Socket.setSoLinger(Unknown Source) at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.shutdown(BHttpConnectionBase.java:305)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.shutdown(DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.java:95) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.shutdown(LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java:98)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolEntry.shutdownConnection(CPoolEntry.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.shutdown(CPoolProxy.java:94)

Comment: PoolableConnection -> increase conn, setTimeToLive, close idle connections, retryhandler, keepalive strategy etc  , Java verison -> jdk1.8.0_251 , Read the certificate from certificate store, sslcontext.createSystemDefault , loadKeyMaterial()..   Use NoOpHostNameVerifier, changed to ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER

Comment: Please add the exception trace in the question. It will help us to narrow down the problem. Because the SSL/ TLS handshake could fail for a plethora of reasons. Please clarify these doubts. 1) Is the cert used by the server issued by a trusted CA or is it self signed? 2) Are you trying to perform client cert authentication?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250102/any-apache-httpclient-4-4-example-for-trust-self-signed-certificates Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes Saravana I have tried the link you have shared. Yes the certificate is a trusted one, and i am invoking a https call using Windows Certificate Store, then only i am gettng handshake issue. I am not facing any issue when reading from pkcs12 file.